# How can I implement in python spacy so the program doesn't match the word if there is any other word that we choose is in the sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

So i want the program to match with the word "ptu", which is easy but lets say I want it to not match if the senetence contains "ptu switch". how can i implement that?

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Define the pattern to match "PTU switch"
pattern1 = [{'LOWER': 'ptu'}, {'LOWER': 'switch', 'IS_STOP': True}]

# Add the pattern to the matcher
matcher.add("PTU_SWITCH", [pattern1])

# Process the text and check for matches
doc = nlp("ptu switch was replaced")
matches = matcher(doc)

# Print the result
if matches:
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
        span = doc[start:end]
        print(str(span))
            
else:
    print("PTU not found.")
```

I tried using this but it would still match it with PTU if switch is there.
I dont want to write if statements to address because i dont wanna hardcode it but rather purely from a pattern i can address it.

Answer (score 0):

`IS_STOP` is not what you're looking for. If you want "ptu" followed by any token that is not "switch", you can use the `!` operator:

```py
pattern1 = [{'LOWER': 'ptu'}, {'LOWER': 'switch', 'OP': '!'}]
```

Note that this requires there to be some token to match following "ptu", so it wouldn't match "ptu" as the last token in a doc.

If you need more complicated filtering or post-processing, you can often put it in an `on_match` callback.

Comment: how would I address if  "ptu" is the last token in a doc?